# Can't get .foreach iterator to post multiple lines

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, invoice

> ```
> function myFunction() {
>   /////////////////////////////////////Fill planning/decor package
> var managementSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1P3EF4Edu0efzJVV1Sx-0ayAPaAAiRK8Sl0Y1qZHmcf4");
> var packageSheet = managementSheet.getSheetByName("Order Contents");
>
> //Order Contents iterater
> var c = packageSheet.getMaxColumns();
> var n = packageSheet.getLastRow();
> var items = packageSheet.getRange(2,1,n,c).getValues();
> var filteredItems = items.filter(function(row) {
>   if(row[2].toString().includes(firstName +" "+lastName))
>   {
> var results =new Array();
> var info = new Array();
> info[0]=row[3];
> info[1]=row[5];
> info[2]=row[9];
> info[3]=row[14];
> info[4]=row[15];
> info[5]=row[16];
> results[0]= info;
> // result = results.every().valueOf();
>  Logger.log(results)
>   var row=22
>   results.forEach(function(value, index)  {
>   Logger.log("The value at index " + index + " is " + value + ".");
>  generatedInvoice.getRange(22,1,1,7).setValues([[info[0],,info[1],info[2],info[3],info[4],info[5]]])
>   row= index + 22+1
> })}})
> }
> ```

Hello. First off, I'm new to appscript/javascript/script in general... Secondly, I'm the worst at explaining things and am so over this as I've been working on it for 2 days with only a few food/water/sleep breaks and just can't figure it out.

I'm trying to take rows from one sheet and copy only some of that row's values to a template...

Customer orders are on one sheet.

Order CONTENTS(for all customers' orders) are on another sheet.

I want to generate an invoice containing everything that the customer has ordered. The code I have currently lists only the final row of the "results" array into my template sheet. I want all of the items that the customer ordered to be added to the invoice. I'm trying to figure out how to use "index" to move to the next line and add the next set of values, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. By logging info, I see that everything is being called correctly and adding to the correct spot in the template. The problem is that it only adds the final line of data into the template when I want all of the lines that match a customer's name.

Comment: Please format your code and fix the typos (such as `info[0],,info[1]`)

Comment: javascript tag can be added.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That's not a typo. The values only go into the correct columns this way as columns A and B are used for the first value. Everything is working correctly, it's just that the values are going into the same line, not skipping to the next, so I only end up with 1 product on the invoice when there are multiple in the data.